SQL Separate a string into distinct fields. Variable length and variable number of elements
How can I separate a single string with components delimited by a fixed value. The number of components varies between 1 and 3, and the components themselves vary in length.
Delimiter is always ::
For Example
123 South Street::London::England
99 North Avenue::Swindon::England
5 West Road::Manchester
10 East Lane

Output required, 3 fields



Street
City
Country




123 South Street
London
England


99 North Avenue
Swindon
England


5 West Road
Manchester



10 East Lane





I've got in a complete mess with nested substrings, and I can't untangle it.

Just be careful. The question marked as a duplicate has a LOT of really bad examples of splitting strings. The accepted answer is one of them. A loop is NOT the right way to split strings. Run away from those answers immediately if not sooner.

@SeanLange I relinked to a better dupe. STRING_SPLIT has made its way to second from top.

Of course, the best solution is fixing the schema to handle this in the client app, before ever even inserting/updating the data in the first place, because a schema putting delimited data into columns really is broken.

If 2016+, take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/Nkobx2LL  I tend to like a bit of JSON for such items.
